# How to apply this sidebar to all pages using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 different html web pages. The html code below is for a menubar which I want to apply to all four pages. Is there any way I can do this using CSS instead of copying/pasting this menubar html code on all 4 of my html web pages? Basically the four pages are Home, News, Contact, About. Whenever someone clicks on a menubar item, it will redirect them to one of the 4 pages. And on all 4 of those pages, I want the menubar to be displayed. I want to create a CSS file which I can just link all 4 pages to and then the menubar will be displayed (code below). Thanks in advance!

Is there any way I can create a CSS file which at least takes care of the styling? And I will manually add the menubar buttons to each html page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="page1.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="page4.html">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any server side language you can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't/can't do this with CSS. You need either:

<s>- **For a non-programmatic solution:** `<link rel="import" href="sidebar.html">` save your sidebar in a `sidebar.html` file and call it with this snippet. Check out the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) for this function.</s>   [(Deprecated)](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376)

- Use ES modules: [Is there a way to use es6 modules to import html template into javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214686/is-there-a-way-to-use-es6-modules-to-import-html-template-into-javascript)
- Use a template engine to produce the results you want.
- Include it with PHP like so: `<?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?>`

There are more solutions, but these are the most obvious AFAIK.

Comment: I had no idea there was a pure HTML way to do this.

Comment: @FaustoNA, if you wouldn't mind, can you add, in the answer, that the support the html imports is terrible at this moment, with chrome being the only major browser that supports it?

Comment: As of Feb 2020 HTML import support has been [depreciated](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376)

Comment: Off-topic: it's spelled deprecated without the i.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this with HTML and CSS only. If you have PHP server then, I suggest to create a PHP file and put your nav-bar code and then use the following PHP code in the all pages.

```
<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>
```

Here is the code for `nav.php`:

```
<?php
echo 
'<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="page1.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="page4.html">About</a></li>
</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: <?php include 'nav.php'; ?> Where exactly do I place this code in my html pages? Under body, head?

Comment: @javaprogrammer First you need to create `nav.php` file, and paste the code I provided you. After that use `<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>` in the HTML page where you want to display the nav bar.

Comment: but where does the <?php include 'nav.php'; ?>
 go in the html file? Which part of the html file do I place it?

Comment: `<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>` this goes in the place where you want to display the navbar, yeah in the HTML file.

Comment: you need to have PHP installed on the server

Comment: Very good and simple instruction. One thing I would like to add is that the page where you put the <?php include 'nav.php'; ?> must also be a php page.

Answer (score 1):

Not with CSS, you have following options:

- Use web component and javascript <sup>(1)</sup> to load it.
- [Jade template engine](http://jade-lang.com/) which is a language for writing HTML templates, produces HTML and supports dynamic code with the support for reusability (DRY), it gives you the ability to include <sup>(2)</sup> partial HTML files in `.jade` with this command

  ```
  include ./path/to/sidebar.jade
  ```

  Example from Jade:

  ```
  //- index.jade
  doctype html
  html
    include ./includes/head.jade
  body
    h1 My Site
    p Welcome to my super lame site.
    include ./includes/foot.jade
  ```
- Server-Side solution like PHP or ASP.NET.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(1)</sup> http://webcomponents.org/

<sup>(2)</sup> http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that by css, html is in charge of the elements and css only of styling them, you can't create elements by css.
I suggest you to copy and paste the code. Or look for other tools, populate it with js, php or something.